# Prove A is an open set if and only if $A \cap Bd(A) = \emptyset $

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Prove A  is an open set if and only if $A \cap Bd(A) = \emptyset $

Here is my start:
Suppose A is an open set.  We know $X-A$ is closed. Need to show $A \cap Bd(A) = \emptyset$
Let $ x \in A$.

Going the other direction, Suppose $ A \cap Bd(A) = \emptyset$. Need to show $A$ is an open set.

Let $x \in A$.  since $x \in A$ $x \notin Bd(A)$

Am I headed in the right direction? I feel more confident about where I have started for the second part then the 1st.

Comment: What is your definition of boundary?

Comment: Let $(X, \mathfrak T) $ be a topological space and let $ A \subseteq X.$ A point $ x \in X$ is in the boundary of A if every open set containing $ x$ intersects both $A$ and $X-A$.

Comment: OK I've edited the proof with hints for your definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can knock out the first direction with a little set algebra.

$(\implies)$ Suppose $A$ is open, meaning $A = A^\circ$. Then we have $$\begin{align} A \cap \text{Bd}(A) = A \cap (\overline{A}\setminus A^\circ) \\ =  A \cap (\overline{A}\setminus A) \\ = A \cap (\overline{A}\cap A^c) \\ = (A\cap A^c)\cap \overline{A} \\ = \emptyset \cap \overline{A} \\ = \emptyset\end{align}$$

$(\impliedby)$ Now suppose $A \cap \text{Bd}(A) = \emptyset $ but for the sake of contradiction we will additionally assume that $A$ is not open. Then there is an element $x \in A$ such that no open set containing $x$ is a subset of $A$. But $A^\circ$ is always open and $A^\circ \subset A$ so $x\notin A^\circ$. This means $x \in \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$, or that $x$ is a boundary point of $A$. Since $x$ is an element of $A$ and an element of the boundary, then $x\in A\cap\text{Bd}(A) \neq \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is open. Then let $x \in A$. Then $A$ is an open set containing $x$ that does not intersect with $X \setminus A$. So $x$ is not in the boundary.

Suppose the intersection of the boundary of $A$ and $A$ is empty. Then all points of $A$ are not in the boundary. So for every $x \in A$, there exists an open set $U_x$ containing x that does not intersect with $A$ or $X \setminus A$.  Obviously $U_x$ must intersect with $A$ as $x \in A$. So it cannot intersect with $X \setminus A$. That means $U_x \subseteq A$. (why?) Now every point $i$ in $A$ is contained in an open set $U_i$, contained in $A$. What is the union of all these open sets? What does that imply about $A$?

Comment: For the first part how do you know that $A$ is an open set containing $x$ that does not intersect with $X-A$. I thought that was what I was trying to prove?

Comment: You supposed that $A$ is open. Clearly $A$ does not intersect with $X \setminus A$. Clearly if $x\in A$, $A$ contains $x$.

Comment: Ah because $A$ is open it doesn't intersect with $X-A$ otherwise it would not be open?

Comment: Nope, this is basic set theory. $X\setminus A$ is the set of all the points in $X$ that are not in $A$. So no point in $X$ can be in both $A$ and $X\setminus A$.

Comment: Okay clearing I am over-thinking this and forgetting everything I learned about set theory!

Comment: Haha, that happens to everyone. Just relax and "follow your nose" for this type of question. Feel free to ask if you are still unclear.

Comment: The discussion is getting long and stackexchange is badgering me to move this to chat. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23058/discussion-between-ilham-and-alyssa-wallace).

Answer (score 0):

for the first direction we can say that BdA is the intersection of closure(A) and closure(X\A). If x belongs to both A and BdA then x belongs to both A and closure(X\A) but X\A is closed (since A is open) so closure(X\A) is X\A. So x belongs to both A and X\A which can't be true.

For the other direction if x belongs to A then it doesn't belong to BdA. So x belongs to either the int(X\A) or intA. The first case is not true so x is in the interior of A which means A is open.

Comment: Her definition is different from the usual definition of boundary, so I changed my argument below.

Comment: If every open set containing x intersects both A and X\A = x belongs to both closure(A) and closure(X\A). I don't see the difference.

Comment: They're equivalent of course, just restated differently, which is what I meant. Just wanted to give you a heads-up that I had changed my entire post from when you read it since you referred to my name in your answer.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

By the symmetry of the definition, it is clear that
$$
\operatorname{Bd}(A)=\operatorname{Bd}(X\setminus A)
$$
Since $A\cap B=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $B\subseteq X\setminus A$, for any subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, the statement is equivalent to

> $C$ is closed if and only if $\operatorname{Bd}(C)\subseteq C$

It also follows from the definition that any point in the boundary of a set $B$ belongs to the closure of $B$.

So, if $C$ is closed we have $\operatorname{Bd}(C)\subseteq C$.

Conversely, suppose $\operatorname{Bd}(C)\subseteq C$ and let $x$ belong to the closure of $C$. If a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ doesn't intersect $X\setminus C$, then $U\subseteq C$, so $x\in C$. If all neighborhoods of $x$ intersect $X\setminus C$, then $x\in\operatorname{Bd}(C)$, so $x\in C$ as well.

---

Your direction is good, however.

Suppose $A\cap\operatorname{Bd}(A)=\emptyset$ and let $x\in A$. Then $x\notin\operatorname{Bd}(A)$ and so a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ doesn't intersect $X\setminus A$, which means $U\subseteq A$. Then…

Suppose $A$ is open and let $x\in A$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\subseteq A$. Therefore…